# Check internet connectvity Android

Tags: android

i am trying bellow code

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null
&& !conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()
&& !conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable())
```

how ever it causes the app to crash

when i use

```
if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null)
```

every thing works fine

what is proper way to use

```
conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()
conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable())
```

the ! is causing issues???

Comment: make sure you have added permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Your code is just carelessly wrong - don't you mean to check is comMgr is NOT null before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo()==Null` then you have problem checking `!conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()` cause you can not check a method like `isConnected()` on Null value.

You should change the code like below:

```
private boolean checkInternetConnection()
{    
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService (Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  

        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null    
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()    
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) 
        {

           return true;    
        }
        else 
        {
        return false;    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional logic is flawed:

```
if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null
&& !conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()
&& !conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable())
```

Only if `getActiveNetworkInfo()` returns null, you're calling a method on the return value (which is null). `&&` is short-circuiting, meaning in `A && B` the `B` is only evaluated if `A` was true.

You probably want to have `||` in place of `&&` here. It is similarly short-circuiting, meaning in `A || B` the `B` is only evaluated if `A` was false.

Comment: i was refering an example from http://techiedreams.com/android-simple-rss-reader/

Comment: i was confused with this part itself already getActiveNetworkInfo() returns null and again we are checking conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() this just didnt seem right

Answer (score 0):

Use this method -

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

and you need to add permission as well -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
private boolean isConnected(Context context){   
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo=null;   
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        networkInfo=connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (!networkInfo.isAvailable()) {
            networkInfo=connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        }   
    }   
    return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected(); 
}
```

You have to take permission in **manifest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```